# navigate to another angular page 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I'm studying angular and would like to navigate to another page when I click on the button. it happens to me that when I click they add the component of the second page under the button. I followed a thousand tutorials but I don't get the desired result!

```
    <a class="card" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/prenota" > 
   <span style="margin: 14px;">Prenota</span> </a>


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'prenota', component: PrenotaComponent },
  { path: 'visualizza', component: VisualizzaComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quick example on StackBlitz?

Comment: I think you miss <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: i added <router-outlet></router-outlet> on app.component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
   <a class="card" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/prenota"> 
   <span style="margin: 14px;">Prenota</span> </a>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: thanks, I added  <router-outl et></router-outlet> where you suggested but the situation does not change! they add the second component below the first ...

Comment: You mean your routing component adds under the buttons?